# How do I get an object from S3 using it's pre-signed url in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have generated a pre-signed url for an object in one of my buckets using boto3:

```
s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<>', 'Key': '<>.json'}, ExpiresIn = 100)
```

Now, how do I `get_object` it in boto3? [The boto3's `get_object` reference](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) doesn't specify any argument for a pre-signed url.

**So, how do I get that object from S3 using it's pre-signed url in boto3?**

Comment: Use `requests` to make `GET` request to the url.

Comment: Pre-signed url is mean for people to get it downloaded DIRECTLY using https protocol, instead of using api with authentication token key.

Comment: Why would you want to use a pre-signed URL to retrieve an object via boto? You would normally provide credentials to boto so that it can access content via an API call rather than a pre-signed URL.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a pre-signed URL, you don't need boto -- you can download the object using any HTTP user agent library.

Conversely, if you have boto and the credentials, you don't need a pre-signed URL.

Pre-signed URLs are intended for allowing someone with credentials to enable someone else without credentials to access a resource, without exposing the credentials to them.

A pre-signed URL includes the access-key-id and possibly a session-token, but not the access-key-secret, and are computationally-infeasible to reverse-engineer... and in this sense, they do not expose the credentials in a way that allows the entity possessing the pre-signed URL to use the associated credentials for any other purpose.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this code to get the result.

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': 'your-s3-bucket', 'Key': 'filepath/inside-bucket/filename.json'}, ExpiresIn = 100)
print(resp)
```

if any doubt please let me know.